# multiple CPU's usage symetrical

Tags: multithreading, multiprocessing, cpu, cpu-usage

I have noticed this a number of times while doing computational expensive tasks on my computer, anywhere from computing hashes, to rendering videos.

In this specific situation I was rendering a video using all 4 of my cores under Linux, and when I opened my system monitor once again I noticed it.

2 or more of my cores were under symmetrical usage, when one went up the other went down completely symmetrical and in sync.

I have no idea why this is the case and would love to know!

[System monitor picture](https://www.dropbox.com/s/fusjb558nrj50gl/Screenshot%20from%202013-05-13%2020:17:33.png)